# How to make my dependency available to other developers?

Tags: java, maven

I recently created my own API in maven, and I need to make the dependency available to others. I have tried using the dependency in another project, but it can't find it. What do I need to do in order to publish it?
My dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.dec4234</groupId>
<artifactId>JavaDestinyAPI</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Available on [GitHub](https://github.com/dec4234/JavaDestinyAPI)

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload your library to a Maven repository. By default, every Maven project uses the Maven Central repository - which contains copies of most common publicly available libraries that you are probably used to using by just putting an entry in the `<dependencies>` section of your `pom.xml`.

Here is a guide to uploading a library to Maven Central - https://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html. I've personally used it previously and whilst it does take some work, its probably your best option.

You can also host your own Maven repository, but I'll leave detailing that route to someone else's answer.